# Mean and STD for values based on key in a single dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, dictionary

I have a below dictionary with N number of keys having some values.

```
a = {'Test': [5, 6, 4, 1, 1, 8], 'Test1': [1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 4], 'Test2': [4, 6, 8], 'TestN': [1, 10, 12]}
```

Each key in a dictionary may have different number of values.

I am trying to get the mean and standard deviation of this dictionary based on the keys

When I tried for

```
vals = [i for i in a.values()]
print(vals)

print(np.mean(vals))
print(np.std(vals))

print(np.array(list(a.values())).mean())
```

Am getting the result of mean and std for all the values irrespective of the key as in the vals am getting all the values

Expected: (Demo values)

Mean

```
a = {'Test': 2, 'Test1': 3, 'Test2': 4, 'TestN': 5}
```

Standard Deiation

```
a = {'Test': 1.6272, 'Test1': 3.7373, 'Test2': 4.2333, 'TestN': 5.3333}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can loop through the dictionary:

```
import numpy as np
a = {'Test': [5, 6, 4, 1, 1, 8], 'Test1': [1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 4], 'Test2': [4, 6, 8], 'TestN': [1, 10, 12]}
means = {key:np.mean(value) for key, value in a.items() }
stdv = {key:np.std(value) for key, value in a.items() }
print(means)
print(stdv)
```

output:

```
{'Test': 4.166666666666667, 'Test1': 2.0, 'Test2': 6.0, 'TestN': 7.666666666666667}
{'Test': 2.544056253745625, 'Test1': 1.1547005383792515, 'Test2': 1.632993161855452, 'TestN': 4.784233364802441}
```